# Error: Failed to run "javac -version" while running cordova build

Tags: java, ubuntu

I use the JDK in my NetBeans Java webservice by just pointing the directory where I've downloaded it to the project on NetBeans. Cant I do the same to build my Ionic APK? I tried setting the JAVA_HOME inside `.bashrc` with this line

```
export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/Apps/jdk1.8.0_144
```

But it didnt work, I dont get any return from `java -version` in terminal.

Comment: javac is in your /bin folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable should be set, but also JDK binaries should be on your `PATH`:

```
JAVA_HOME=$HOME/Apps/jdk1.8.0_144
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
```